# Making library from cpp and hh file

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, linker

I have an xx.cpp and xx.hh file and want to link xx.obj file with a library which is made by others cpp and hh file...how to do that?
can i made a library of xx.obj?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on the kind of access you have to the different sources and which development tools you use. 
2 solutions come into my mind:

1. If you have direct access to the sources of the second library you can simply add the xx-sources directly to that library, recompile and relink.
2. If you don't have direct access to the xx-sources and you've got only the xx-object file you can add that object file directly into your project (as if they were regular source files). I know that this works with visual studio,  but the xx-object-file has to be compiled with the same compiler version and settings (do not mix debug/release, static/dynamic runtimelibrary)